# how to get php executable path file of a system remotely?

Tags: php, eclipse, php.ini, zend

I want to debug php codes and I am using zend debugger in Eclipse environment and I have a remote server access(ftp). I used PHP_BINDIR to find out about the path file of the php executable file:

```
echo PHP_BINDIR
```

it results in:

```
/usr/local/zend/bin
```

but because it is remote I don't know the path file. I am on windows 7 is it possible to find out the address? and my url for example:

example.com/usr/local/zend/bin

does not work either, eclipse tells this address does not exist

Comment: Why do you think there is any php binary at all?  If they are running mod_php, then there is no binary you can run directly.  It is all in the Apache module, that is only useful to Apache.

Comment: @Zoredache so if it's the case what should I do? sorry I didn't understand your idea